# ipv6addr_secondaries not properly working centos7

Tags: networking, centos, linux-networking, centos7, ipv6

Hello I tried to configure additional ipv6 addresses on my centos 7 server but it seems different from centos 6.

this used to work on my centos6 server BUT NOT ON my CENTOS 7
`IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES="2602:fde2:0fc0:0128:1111:2222:1212:10/44 \
2602:fde2:0fc0:0028:1111:2222:1212:11/44"`

Both of these ip's were not pingable with ping6.
However if I just add 1 ip it works

```
IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES=2602:fde2:0fc0:0128:1111:2222:1212:10/44
```

this works for example.

But it's only 1 ipv6 how can I add more than 1 with IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES.

**EDIT:**
this is my eth0 config

`# Created by cloud-init on instance boot automatically, do not edit.
#
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
DEVICE=eth0
DNS1=1.1.1.1
DNS2=9.9.9.9
GATEWAY=23.XXX.32.65
IPADDR=23.XXX.32.94
IPV6ADDR=2602:fde2:fc0::37/44
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=2602:fde2:fc0::1
NETMASK=255.255.255.224
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=no
IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES="2602:fde2:0fc0:0128:1111:2222:1212:10/44 \
2602:fde2:0fc0:0028:1111:2222:1212:11/44"`

Comment: This should work fine. Exactly what did you put in the configuration?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I added my eth0 config from /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0. I checked it with ping6 and it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you actually have a backslash and newline in there, or did you add that when posting it here? The first thing I would do would be to get rid of them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thats it I deleted the backslash and it works now. Earlier when I was trying to configure it with just spaces as said in the manual I did not add the ip's inside the "" tags. Thanks alot I've been busy on this for several days already. Centos7  is so much different from centos 6

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is the solution for me. You have to delete the backslash.

Example

`IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES="2602:fde2:0fc0:0128:1111:2222:1212:10/44 \
2602:fde2:0fc0:0028:1111:2222:1212:11/44"`

Becomes

```
IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES="2602:fde2:0fc0:0128:1111:2222:1212:10/44 2602:fde2:0fc0:0028:1111:2222:1212:11/44"
```

I don't know why this is. If it is the difference between centos6 and 7 or if it is just the difference between my machines.

THanks @MichaelHampton for the solution.

Comment: BTW: IPv6 addresses by default have a /64 "netmask". one exception is ::1/128 but by definition IPv6 interface addresses use a prefix length of 64bits